# Command-line arguments in C++

Tags: c++

Many of my programs take in command-line arguments, one example is as follows:

```
a.out [file-name] [col#] [seed]
```

Then if I want to use the arguments, I have nice, easy-to-use functions such as:

```
atof(argv[..]) and atoi(argv[..])
```

I was wondering if such easy/simple functions exist for C++. I tried to simply do this:

```
cin >> col_num >> seed;
```

But that doesn't work... It waits for an input (not command-line) and then outputs it...

Thanks

Comment: `atof` and `atoi` are available from C++ if you believe they meet your needs.

Comment: why do you suddenly stop using `argv`?  I mean...that *is* the argument array...

Comment: Oh. I thought those were C functions (obviously compatible in C++). I was just wondering if there was a more C++ ish way of doing it

Comment: Does your implementation support [stof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/stof) and [stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/stol) yet?  I know MSVC10 does, but I don't think any other compiler does yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [equivalent of atoi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050701/equivalent-of-atoi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Solution 1:***
You can use `lexical_cast` in place of `atoi`

```
int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>("12345");
```

Use `boost::lexical_cast` in try-catch block though. It throws `boost::bad_lexical_cast` when the cast is invalid.

***Solution 2:***
If you are not using Boost and need a standard C++ solution you can use streams.

```
std::string hello("123"); 
std::stringstream str(hello); 
int x;  
str >> x;  
if (!str) 
{      
  // The conversion failed.      
}
```

Comment: Boost looks awesome. I'm gonna play around with it for a bit and see what I get. I might switch to `boost::program_options`, it looks like it'll do the trick. Though `lexical_cast` will work for now :) Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

`ato*` family is crappy, and cannot signal errors properly. In C++ you want to use either `boost::lexical_cast` or a full-blown command-line parser like `boost::program_options`.

Comment: +1 for boost::program_options it makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save yourself the hard work of parsing the cmd line arguments yourself you can always use a library such as [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to use streams and `>>` operator, you can use `stringstream`:

```
double a; // or int a or whatever
stringstream(argv[1]) >> a;
```

You need to include `<sstream>`

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `atof` and `atoi`.

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    float f = std::atof(argv[1]);
    int i = std::atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

But you can use more generic facilities like `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: Too hard to detect errors with ato?(). When I type `command '15 2' plop` by mistake it will miss the 2 completely. The argument against this is `people are not that stupid`. I would agree but scripts are, and a lot of commands are used in scripts where the arguments are substituted in and these things should be checked.